# Converting Table to LaTeX and calling inline R Markdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, gtsummary, gt

I'm trying to use gtsummary with R Markdown but it doesn't support it directly. So I took a `gtsummary` table, converted it into LaTeX and stored it in a variable `latex_code`. The intent was to call it inline but it doesn't seem to work. My code:

````
```{r}
library(gt)
library(gtsummary)
#Table comparison of filtered and unfiltered dataset. 
comp <- mtcars %>% select(mpg, cyl, disp)
latex_code <- comp %>% tbl_summary(by = cyl) %>% as_gt() %>% as_latex()

latex_code %>% as.character() %>% cat()
```

`r latex_code`
````

I get the following error:

```
! Argument of \@iiminipage has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.281 \end{table}
```

Comment: What `rmarkdown` version are you using? For me it renders without any problem.

Comment: I'm using Version 2.21

Comment: Please update your post with your R markdown header (yaml). I am confused why you need to manually create latex code, rather than just specifying the output type as PDF.

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg I'm writing for a journal and I might have to provide the latex file. This is my first time using an Rmd so I wanted to be careful especially since the documentation says pdf is error prone in gt :). Either way, I don't know what the ghost in the machine did but my code is working today. Also, I love `gtsummary` and would thank you and your team for it.

Answer (score 1):

gtsummary has tons of printing options for R Markdown and Quarto (see: https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/rmarkdown.html).

Some sensible print engine defaults are chosen based on your setup (e.g. gt or flextable), but you can try any of the print options listed in that vignette for R Markdown.

Comment: I have seen that and in fact that is pretty much what I am doing here: using `as_gt`, then `as_latex`. Ultimately I want a latex file.